# Square wave distortion on low frequencies

Tags: frequency, pulse, wave, square, distortion

I have this old Soviet low frequency sine and square pulse generator "G3-36A".

[image]

I ran into an interesting problem.

When I try to generate square pulse under 100Hz I get a distorted wave. Like in the image:

[image]

When I increase frequency to 100Hz this is what I get:

[image]

At 1kHz it looks more like a square:

[image]

Does anyone know what is causing the distortion and how can I fix it?

Schematic of the signal generator:

[image]

The KT603B transistors circled with red color are the ones that generate square wave. The blue ones are amplifiers.

Comment: Is your scope set to AC coupling? This is what an AC-coupled square wave looks like.

Comment: so its about scope, and nothing to do with generator, kinda fell stupid rn ngl

Comment: Well it's the scope if your scope is set to AC coupled.

Comment: well guess i have to check that tomorrow and come back with results

Comment: Note if the unit has any wax or paper capacitors inside, they are probably faulty.  [Mr. Carlson's Lab](https://www.youtube.com/c/MrCarlsonsLab) can show you how to identify these.

Comment: The icons on your scope seem to suggest AC coupling.

Comment: yep i will change it to dc tomorrow and upload results, hopefully that's the only problem,

Comment: The generator has a coupling capacitor feeding the output transistors and another coupling capacitor at its output. A good squarewave needs DC coupling.

Comment: The schematic shows a 200uF (MKF) output capacitor and some internal coupling capacitors. So calculate the time constant that provides with whatever load you had on the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely isn't a problem with your waveform generator, but with the oscilloscope you're measuring it with. I'm not familiar with Owon scopes, but I assume that this ~ symbol here: [image] refers to AC coupling.

When a scope is AC coupled, it's applying a high-pass filter to everything it displays to filter out the DC component. A square wave under a high-pass filter looks like this:

[image]

([image source](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_3.html))

Note how it looks different depending on the frequency, just like your square wave.

The other possibility is that something in the waveform generator itself is applying a high-pass filter to its output, either intentionally or due to a fault. This seems significantly less likely to me, however.

Comment: i was just reading about this, once i change to dc will let you know. i was thinking that either transistor or capacitor next to it was faulty but they seemed to work properly so i guess it's me being stupid  not using scope properly xD, thanks again really helped out

Comment: ill post update